# How does one check an entity for updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here's the setup:
My app uses entity framework to insert a request (row) into a table.
A service on the network monitors the table, runs the request, then updates the row with the outcome.

Is there an easy way to monitor my entity so that I know when it's been updated?

If it helps the requests shouldn't take long to complete, so I'm kinda expecting:

```
do
{
    thread.sleep(500); 
    // code; 
}while(isDone || !timeout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in to EF for this.

With SQL Server you can have this feature with [query notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx), but you'd have to do it outside of EF.